# Is it OK to revise one's own question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I'm not sure if I should revise my question or post a second question. The situation is that the original question elicited an answer and several comments. This, together with testing more code, has given me insight such that I would now phrase the question differently. Also the sample code would differ fairly significantly (the original simple example was one module, the real context is a module called by another).

Comment: Is it essentially the same question, a follow-up question, or just a different question? *Clarifying* your question is encouraged, but chamaeleon-questions are seen as abusive.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Not really a chamaeleon, more like a Python growing a new skin ... :)

Comment: Hmmm ... Ive read the other Q & A.   It is focusing (mostly) on the specific issue of invalidating posted answers.  Thats not exactly the case here.  I used the word *revision* deliberately to indicate something beyond editing for clarity.   The underlying issue is the same but the revision basically changes the context by making it clear I want an importable module, not a single module solution.
I think I'll probably go ahead and make the revision, and see what happens.

Comment: In that other thread there was an interesting comment about how far one may go in editing another persons question (so not applicable here).  The point was made that one should edit for clarity but not to change the OP's intent.   That makes sense if one thinks of the poster as 'owning' a question.  Could someone please confirm that is NOT really the paradigm here, all questions (and answers) are 'owned' by the community.   That is the only way I can make sense of many of the rules and practices here.   Otherwise, some of the editing, closing etc would be just plain rude.

Answer (score 2):

If the comments help you to understand how to better phrase your question, be it by using the correct terminology or adding missing information, by all means, you should edit it.

If you've got a satisfactory answer to the question that you asked, but that made you think/realize another issue, it warrants a new question. You could, however, link to the original question for additional background information.

Comment: But, at the same point, if the answer prompts a new question, you should use any and all methods of researching the new question before asking another question. You should not go directly from getting an answer to asking another question.

Comment: @Tiny Giant ... hmmm its a bit of a combination.  The sample code isn't really right, the posted 'solutions' (sample code also) don't really work in context.  Im a bit torn between my getting the answer I need (which may happen through the exchange of comments) versus leaving clear information for later readers.